# Please add a "full screen view" button for code parts

Tags: feature-request, code

The need for horizontal scrolling on code is very annoying. Full visibility helps to better understand.
**update:**
Most of the time,the focus is on asking question and giving answer,and not according to the code formatting.
In some cases,wrap the code might be confusing.